# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions- ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a reservation app. I am quite new to React, and I tried searching and I can't seem to find what the problem is.
As my code has over 400 lines I will post only the ones I'm getting an error at.
I am following this article https://medium.com/@kris101/building-appointment-scheduler-app-in-react-and-nodejs-d01f7294a9fd

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKQvu.png)

The specific errors are:

Line 136:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 139:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 147:7:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I tried disabling eslint but when I do so I'm getting more errors.

```
handleDBReponse(response) {
    const reservations = response;
    const today = moment().startOf("day"); //start of today 12 am
    const initialSchedule = {};
    initialSchedule[today.format("YYYY-DD-MM")] = true;
    const schedule = !reservations.length
      ? initialSchedule
      : reservations.reduce((currentSchedule, reservation) => {
          const { slot_date, slot_time } = reservation;
          const dateString = moment(slot_date, "YYYY-DD-MM").format(
            "YYYY-DD-MM"
          );
          !currentSchedule[slot_date]
            ? (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false))
            : null;
          Array.isArray(currentSchedule[dateString])
            ? (currentSchedule[dateString][slot_time] = true)
            : null;
          return currentSchedule;
        }, initialSchedule);

    for (let day in schedule) {
      let slots = schedule[day];
      slots.length
        ? slots.every(slot => slot === true) ? (schedule[day] = true) : null
        : null;
    }

    this.setState({
      schedule: schedule
    });
  }
```

Comment: In which line it is causing the error ?

Comment: 136 !currentSchedule[slot_date] 139  Array.isArray(currentSchedule[dateString]) 147 slots.length

Comment: can you add the error screenshot please to the post?

Comment: I updated the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see lots of linting issue in the above code.As of now I have fixed Expected an assignment or function call issue.

Please check the below code and let me know if it works

```
handleDBReponse(response) {
    const reservations = response;
    const today = moment().startOf('day'); // start of today 12 am
    const initialSchedule: any = {};
    initialSchedule[today.format('YYYY-DD-MM')] = true;
    const schedule = !reservations.length
        ? initialSchedule
        : reservations.reduce((currentSchedule: any, reservation: any) => {
            const tempSchedule = currentSchedule;
            const { slot_date, slot_time } = reservation;
            const dateString = moment(slot_date, 'YYYY-DD-MM').format('YYYY-DD-MM');
            tempSchedule[dateString] = !tempSchedule[slot_date] ? (tempSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false)) : null;
            if (Array.isArray(tempSchedule[dateString])) {
                tempSchedule[dateString][slot_time] = true;
            }
            return test;
        }, initialSchedule);

    for (const day in schedule) {
        const tempSchedule = schedule;
        const slots = tempSchedule[day];
        const checkEverySlot = slots.every((slot: boolean) => slot === true);
        if (slots.length && checkEverySlot) {
            tempSchedule[day] = true;
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        schedule,
    });
}
```

Note: It is good practice to write identifier in camel case.

Comment: It's still generating it at this line  slots.length ? (slots.every((slot) => slot === true) ? (schedule[day] = true) : null) : null;

Comment: @Victoria I have updated the code please check now.

Comment: Dude It seams whole application has eslint issue. You need to fix one by one. If your app needs to deliver promptly then I would suggest you to disable eslint rules temporarily.

Comment: You forget to import this in App.jsx. import React, { Component } from 'react';

Comment: if I do so it says Module not found: Can't resolve 'moment' in 'D:\Faculta\WT\proj\api\reservation-scheduler\src\components' but there is no file named moment

Comment: Have you installed moment library?. Share me the package.json file

Comment: npm i moment --save

Comment: @Victoria. You are not installed momentjs. Execute above command and restart the server

Comment: Thank you! Now it's failing to save the reservation but the app opens and looks well.

Comment: Awesome go ahead. If I get time I will help you to resolve your further queries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is around your use of ternary statements;

```
!currentSchedule[slot_date] ? (currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false)) : null;
```

```
Array.isArray(currentSchedule[dateString]) ? (currentSchedule[dateString[slot_time] = true) : null
```

```
slots.length ? slots.every(slot => slot === true) ? (schedule[day] = true) : null : null;
```

You can't use ternary statements in this way, you should replace these with individual if statements

e.g

```
if(currentSchedule[slot_date]) currentSchedule[dateString] = Array(8).fill(false)
```

An example of a proper use of ternaries would be when assigning a variable:

```
let myVar = x === 10 ? 'x is 10' : 'x is not 10'
```

Comment: I fixed it as you said and I'm getting the same as in the upper comment https://imgur.com/a/aMKkWTJ

Answer (score -1):

The function `handleDBReponse` doesn't seems to be a well defined function. Try adding public before its name. Like `public handleDBReponse(response) {...}`.

Comment: I tried this and it's saying  Line 124:10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: `public` is not valid syntax in vanilla javascript.